# Calling multiple methods on same same object without any references

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've created a costume view,
and mostly it does not require to have a reference to it,
when instantiate, its enough to call its methods and to set its values all at once.

so my question is:
how do I allow calling multiple methods on an object with no reference

e.g

```
AlertDialog.Builder(view.context)  
    .setTitle(title)  
    .setMessage(msg)  
    .show()
```

**HOW DO THEY DO THAT**

Comment: Please check AlertDialog.Java file, so you can get better idea about it. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you also tagged Kotlin, there's a good alternative there not available in Java. E.g. if you didn't have `AlertDialog.Builder`, and methods like `setTitle(title)` were only defined on `AlertDialog` (and don't `return this` so they can't be chained), you could write

```
val dialog = AlertDialog(...).apply {
    title = "some title" // calls setTitle
    message = "some message"
}
```

see e.g. https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84 or https://kotlinexpertise.com/coping-with-kotlins-scope-functions/ for a discussion of standard scope functions (`apply` is just one of them).

Answer (score 2):

They use [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern

Here is an example in **Java**

```
/**
 * Represents the product created by the builder.
 */
class Car {
    private int wheels;
    private String color;

    public Car() {
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(final String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }

    public void setWheels(final int wheels) {
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [wheels = " + wheels + ", color = " + color + "]";
    }
}

/**
 * The builder abstraction.
 */
interface CarBuilder {
    Car build();

    CarBuilder setColor(final String color);

    CarBuilder setWheels(final int wheels);
}

class CarBuilderImpl implements CarBuilder {
    private Car carTmp;

    public CarBuilderImpl() {
        carTmp = new Car();
    }

    @Override
    public Car build() {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setColor(carTmp.getColor());
        car.setWheels(carTmp.getWheels());
        return car;
    }

    @Override
    public CarBuilder setColor(final String color) {
        carTmp.setColor(color);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public CarBuilder setWheels(final int wheels) {
        carTmp.setWheels(wheels);
        return this;
    }
}

public class CarBuildDirector {
    private CarBuilder builder;

    public CarBuildDirector(final CarBuilder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    public Car construct() {
        return builder.setWheels(4)
                      .setColor("Red")
                      .build();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        final CarBuilder builder = new CarBuilderImpl();

        final CarBuildDirector carBuildDirector = new CarBuildDirector(builder);

        System.out.println(carBuildDirector.construct());
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think it is obligatory to abstract away interface and implementation in Builder pattern.